# Ubuntu encrypted disk and boot problem

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, encryption

After disk format and installation of Ubuntu I have a problem with boot. System doesn't want to start.

There is info: 'boot device not found'

It seems that system doesn't see the bootloader / disk is not mounted.

Could you help me?

My partitions look like this:

[image: gparted partitions list]

I tried to use 'Boot-Repair' tool, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Are you prompted to type your passphrase first ?

Comment: No, the only info was exactly: 
http://imgur.com/a/XbHSN

Comment: Then the BIOS didn't find anything in the MBR. Currently I am puzzeled and confused as I am nearly in the same boat as yours now. I am curious though, if you launched boot-repair from a liveUSB, did you unlock your /dev/sda3 first ?

Comment: I used boot-repair with liveUSB but I hadn't decoded the disk. Unlock i.e. decode?

Comment: Try to decrypt your LUKS parition first and then use boot-repair. To decrypt the partition, click on the partition icon and it'll asks you for your passphrase. If you somehow can't access some GUI, then from a terminal type:  _cryptsetup open /dev/sda3 <TYPE_NAME(e.g. sda3)>_

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed a similar issue on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. The system was stuck booting into an (initramfs) prompt. I have a LUKS encrypted disk as well, so I could just boot from a USB / CD and quickly repair.

I did figure it out this way though. I booted from an ancient BackTrack Linux v5 R3 DVD I had lying around. Once in a terminal, I ran `fdisk -l` to determine that device I was interested in is `/dev/sda5`.

Next, I needed to unlock the device (note that `mydrive` can be replaced with anything you'd like:
`sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 mydrive`

At this point, I was prompted to enter my disk password.

And since I used the LVM on LUKS option provided by the Debian/Ubuntu installer, I need to start up LVM. So I next ran:
`sudo vgchange -aly`.

In my case, this device was now mapped under `/dev/mapper` as `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root`.

Now I can repair:
`sudo fsck -y /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root`

Once it completes, remember to remove:
`sudo vgchange -an /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg`

And close the device:
`sudo cryptsetup luksClose mydrive`

**References:**

- https://serverfault.com/a/375095/18451
- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/VG_activate.html